# How to prevent open task to be closed in Youtrack workflow?

Tags: workflow, youtrack

There are different states in our task like: open, in-progress, fixed, tested, closed. We need to design a workflow to prevent users from closing an opened task.

I went through the documentation an saw codes like this:

```
var user;
if (issue.Assignee == null) {
  user = issue.project.leader;
} else {
  user = issue.Assignee;
}
```

The problem is that codes like above  just check for statuses. I need a way to prevent actions (like closing an open task). How should I prevent users from such actions? How to check if he is closing the task?

In [the documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD65/Issue+Attributes+and+Methods) it's been mentioned how to access issue fields and issue custom fields. But again the code looks like below:

```
if (issue.State == Open) {
    # what to do here how to check if he is closing the task?
}
```

How should I check he is closing the task? What should I do to tell the user you cannot close the open task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of working with the code I found the solution:

```
rule check open state

when issue.State.becomes({Open}) {
    assert issue.State.oldValue == {Submitted}: "Issue needs to be in Submitted state, to make it Open" 
}
```

I had to use `becomes` in order to check whether user is opening the task, and then by using assert I'd make sure if the task is changed from `Submitted` state to open or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. Be aware that either in a when clause of a stateless rule or in the body of the rule you can implement something like State != null && !State.isResolved && (State.oldValue != null && State.oldValue.isResolved)
2. To prevent an issue from being changed, use assert